# Use one domain to make another domain content appear HTTPS secured (HTTPS redirect to website I have no access to)

Tags: redirect, ssl, https

Let's say I have a website, which belongs to me, but because of specific resons I am unable to access FTP or make any changes on server.

This website is not HTTPS secured, runs on HTTP. However I would like to be able to make a secured way of access to this content - for me and for other people on internet.

I am willing to redirect to this website from another domain with HTTPS.

Would it be possible to have another domain (with hosting I have access to), set up SSL there and then use htaccess redirect to the domain without https?

So that you could browse the content in a way, that would make the communication secure, and with keeping HTTPS in URL, even though the URL in adress would be different, than the URL of website I have no access to.

Answer (score 0):

Redirects would not work because they just instruct the browser to visit the other site, directly. What you would need instead is to hide the other http-only site behind your https-enabled site, i.e. reverse proxy functionality. See for example [How to use Apache as Reverse Proxy](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension) or [Use apache as a HTTPS to HTTP Proxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/486042/use-apache-as-a-https-to-http-proxy).

Comment: Thank you very much! :) Great links.